# Starting CMD or Powershell in current folder from windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, explorer

I know that you can start cmd or powershell from windows explorer; when you type "cmd" or "powershell" in current path of the explorer window. But what when you have folders that are named "CMD" or "powershell". I have them both and when I type their names respectively instead of starting them explorer goes in those folders.

Any solutions for this, so I can still type and start those shell from windows explorer from parent folder(i.e. folder that contains "cmd" and "powershell" folders). Thanks xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a subfolder named "cmd" you could type in `%COMSPEC%` instead, and it opens CMD (because it's an environment variable that holds the direct path to cmd.exe, unless you've changed your COMSPEC from the default).

Instead, my suggestion would be to make a couple batch files, with short unique names, to load CMD and/or Powershell.  Put them in your path, and then use the batch file names in the address bar instead.

Comment: I'm just asking generally, didn't know about %comspec%. Thank you xD.

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves using the mouse: if you have the folder open in Windows Explorer, and no other files or folders are selected, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>right-click</kbd> and select `Open command window here`

(This only works for COMSPEC in Windows 7 and higher.)